# SharePoint showing recent "Installed On" date despite not being patched for several months

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have an interesting situation. Within "Program and Features" SharePoint is shown has being installed on January 3rd 2024. Here's the kicker:

- The server is several years ago
- No CUs have been installed recently
- The server has not been patched in the last 60 days (no judgement, please)

What else would cause the installation date to change in Control panel?